# Prove an inequality for the heat equation solution.

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Suppose I have the problem $$u_t=ku_{xx}$$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for a square integrable function $f(x)$.
Prove $$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R} } | u(x,t) | \leq c t^{-1/4} \| f(x) \|$$ for some positive constant $c$.

My attempt so far, using Cauchy Schwartz inequality I get $$\max_x | u |= \max |  \frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \int_{ - \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4k t}} f(y) dy | \leq \max_x \frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \left( \int_{ - \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2k t}} \right)^{1/2} \| f(x) \| $$
I know that $$\max_x \frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4k t}} =\frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} $$
and $$|u_x| \leq A t^{-3/4} \|f(x)|$$ for some other positive constant $A$.

I tried to use those relations but couldn't come up with anything, perhaps if I could explicitly compute $\max_x \frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \left( \int_{ - \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2k t}} \right)^{1/2}$ I may end up with something, but I couldn't find anything useful on how to make this computation, so how can I prove this?

Comment: You can explicitly compute $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2kt}}\,\mathrm dy = 2\sqrt {\pi k t}$$ and your desired result follows. The attempt via Cauchy-Schwarz is correct.

Comment: You do not even need to explicitly compute that integral. Just substitute in a way such that the integrand does not contain $x$ or $t$ anymore and argue why the integral is finite.